# Rewrite URL for a page using tuckey urlrewite

Tags: xml, url-rewriting, redirect, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have not used tuckey urlrewrite previously so I am not sure if I am going in the right direction.

I want to save the query params and just add `#` before the `\page`.

I need to redirect the page from:

```
<from>/page?{big query}</from>
```

to

```
<to>/#/page?{big query}</to>
```

Currently I am trying to use:

```
<rule match-type="wildcard">
<from>/page\?$</from>
<to type="redirect">%{context-path}/#/page?%{query-string}</to>
</rule>
```

But of course this is not working. Can someone help me with this or point me in the right direction?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.